# How to get the key of a deserialized json with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have a json like this

```
    e.result = {
        5474: {
            name: "john",
            last: "doe"
    },
        8471: {...},
        ...
    }
```

I get the data this way

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
foreach (JToken token in o)
{
    Message.show((string)token.First["name"]);
}
```

That work's fine, but i need to get the **key** in each iteration. **Need to get the 5474 and 8471 values** in this example.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((JProperty)token).Name.ToString()
```